# Bang (!) at the beginning of method name

Tags: ruby, prefix-operator

What is the purpose of the exclamation mark right before the `taking_damage` method in this example of code?

```
if warrior.health < 20 && !taking_damage?(warrior)
     warrior.rest!
end
```

Comment: There is no `taking_damage` method, it's `taking_damage?` method.

Answer (score 8):

It is the boolean operation [*Negation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) and thus equivalent to the Ruby keyword `not`.

You can read the line like this:

> “If the warrior's health is below 20 **and** the warrior is **NOT** taking
>   damage **then** the warrior must rest.”

Answer (score 2):

It is the negation operator which takes the method/variable's truthiness and returns the opposite of it.

Answer (score 1):

Also this operator can be used to convert any value to a true and false (Boolean value). Here is an example:

```
 > !nil
 => true 
 > !!nil
 => false
```